# Can questions support the <details> tag?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Today I wanted to include an extra log in a question, but felt it didn't need to take up vertical space when someone first looked at the question (the scrollbar on long code wasn't aggressive enough in my opinion), so I immediately reached for the `<details>` and `<summary>` tags, and was surprised to discover that they're stripped out.

Could these tags be supported? If not, what's the reasoning for not supporting them?

Comment: Do these answer your question?: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352631/3648282 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354002/3648282 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348073/3648282 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272351/3648282

Comment: I don't think so: my case isn't a snippet (it's a debug log that might be useful to someone who can diagnose nginx issues to more accurately answer what's going on) and `<details>` is already a standard HTML tag, not some new custom syntax.

Comment: There are *lots* of html tags that are not supported, not just details which is pretty new. But this tag could be useful, if not used for something nefarious like hiding spam.

Comment: Actually hiding spam from casual view is one good reason why they may not adopt this.

Comment: The details could just always be expanded in moderator view I think. The purpose of the tag would be to make it easier for answerers/questioners to read the post, not to 
substantially change the content. Though it may probably be a problem if what moderator initially sees differs from what users see, I dunno...

Comment: This is most definitely a useful feature that I would like to be added. It's not about "hiding spam". This is about providing all the needed context for a question, in a manner that enhances readability/overall view by allowing to hide memorizable information after a first read. E.g. you may need to provide a schema or json of some data; even with ad-hoc formatting and shortenings, the question may still end up being quite long and scary to review for potential answerers. An appropriate limitation in total characters for a question would still ensure that the `<details>` tag is not abused.